# Binding Issue in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, viewmodel

I have a strange binding issue which i dont understand:

I have a self created List Type called `VirtualizingCollection` which inherits from `IList`. It shall be binded to a `ListView`.

I try it in three different ways. In one way (I dont like it) it works, the other two ways don't.

I implemented my program in MVVM architecture so I try to use a viewmodel to display it (see way 3).

**Way 1 (works):**

XAML Dynamic Resource:

```
<Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="ListView.View">
        ...
```

Code Behind:

```
DataContext = new VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary>(fs, 100);
```

Result:
The Data is shown in the `ListView` but the `DataContext` of all my other Bindings in XAML are gone. So this is no option for me.

**Way 2 (does not work)**

XAML Dynamic Resource:

```
<Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding test}"/>
    <Setter Property="ListView.View">
        ...
```

Code Behind:

```
VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary> test = new VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary>(fs, 100);
```

Result: No Binding Errors in Output detected but the Data is not shown.

**Way3 (does not work)**

XAML Dynamic Resource

```
<Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding test}"/>
    <Setter Property="ListView.View">
        ...
```

Code Behind:

```
myViewModel.x(fs)
```

ViewModel:

```
public VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary> test { get; set; }
public void x(FileSummarizer fs) 
{
       test = new VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary>(fs, 100);
}
```

Result: No Binding Error in Output detected but the Data is not shown.

Comment: Create a dummy converter where the items are bound and check their values when being bound, also use a debug.break in you conversion method to make life easier for you

Comment: The problem with the two non-working methods might be related to `DataContext`s. Is the `DataContext` for the control containing the ListView set to the view model?

Comment: @nondestructive In the Constructor of my CodeBehind i do following: _myViewModel = MyViewModel.Instance;
this.DataContext = _myViewModel;Initialize Component();
Do you mean this?

Comment: I've had it happen to me - while it wasn't obvious from the actual code, the bindings were looking for properties in the wrong places. Well, the DataContext definitely exists, so I'm not sure what could be happening. There are some settings to enable more in-depth binding messages, but I can't remember where.

Comment: Try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for public VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary> test { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Your **1st approach** does work because you are creating `test` before setting the DataContext of your View. Therefor, the data is already present when all the Bindings get resolved.

Your **3rd approach** does not work because there's nothing which notifies your View of changes to your property `test`. If you would set `test` inside the constructor of your ViewModel you should see some data in the View. Right now, there is nothing which triggers an update of your Binding regarding the `test` property. You could do it like this:

```
public void x(FileSummarizer fs) 
{
   test = new VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary>(fs, 100);

   // Now you need to raise an event to notify the view.
   // This line depends on if you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
   // on your ViewModel directly or if you are yousing some ViewModel-Base
   // class. Here's an example how it could look like:
   RaisePropertyChanged("test");
}
```

Also: As Sasha mentioned in the comments, your `VirtualizingCollection` should also implement some sort of `INotifyPropertyChanged` so your View gets notified when the **content** of the collection changes.

Comment: You do not need here RaisePropertyChanged because it implimented in  setter : set{_test = value; RaisePropertyChanged("test");}

Comment: @Sasha Where do you see this line? In his code example the `test` property is an auto-property which means it has the default setter implementation: `public VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary> test { get; set; }`. Of course he could raise the PropertyChanged-event also in the setter but right now he does not.

Comment: If he will implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then in every bindable property will be RaisePropertyChanged. So yes, you are right - right now he doesn't, but he will have to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your view model class should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the `test` property is set:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary> _test;
    public VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary> test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; OnPropertyChanged("test");  }
    }

    public void x(FileSummarizer fs)
    {
        //set the property, not the field:
        test = new VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary>(fs, 100);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding test}"/>
```